# Login required decorator with JWT using django and AngularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, django, jwt, login-required

I have a project with AngularJS, **JWT** and django as back-end framework. JWT user authentication works OK.

At the same time I'm trying

- Send $http.get('/myview/') from my angular service
- To **myview** in django which is decorated with **login_required**.

After research I understand that it shouldn't work because request.session is not set.

***So the question is how can I allow to obtain requests in this view only from authenticated users?***

I have idea to create custom decorator in django that will check the token that will be sent within my get/post request from angular service but I have doubts that it will work.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution. I didn't think that rest framework permission classes can also work as decorator for a view.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def example_view(request, format=None):
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/